# get binary image from S3 via api gateway

Tags: image, aws-api-gateway, imagemap, line-api

What I need is getting an image via https://xxx.yyy/zzz/1040 rest api, and I will show the image to a SNS tool(Line) via imagemap API.

I am trying to get image saved in S3 bucket via lambda. Here is the flow I am trying to implement:

1. Save image to S3
2. Lambda to get base64 image from S3 using aws sdk and return base64 encoded image
3. Config api gateway to convert the base64 image to binary image
4. Hit rest api endpoint to get the real image

**Issue:**

I could not get the real image via both browser and postman

please help! and let me know if you need more detail information...

**Lambda:**

```
'use strict';

const aws    = require('aws-sdk');
const s3     = new aws.S3({ region: 'ap-northeast-1' });
const BUCKET = 'test';

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('====== started ====');
    s3.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: 'line-service-menu-option2.jpg' }).promise()
    .then(data => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
            body: data.Body.toString('base64'),
            isBase64Encoded: true,
        });
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
};
```

**lambda test log**

> {   "statusCode": 200,   "headers": {
>       "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"   },   "body": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wC***********************",
>   "isBase64Encoded": true }

**api gateway configuration**

[API setting][1] [method request][2] [integration request][3] [integration response][4] [method response][5]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvt13.jpg   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2tns.jpg   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/poNHl.jpg   [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgVf8.jpg   [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS00q.jpg

Comment: Why no use s3 proxy from api gateway to read the binary file directly?

Comment: Thanks, Kannaiyan! Will try and feedback soon.